# Flutter Chewie video player's controls are misaligned

Tags: flutter

Chewie video player widget has satisfactory alignment and overall UI for iOS (red borders are added by me for testing purposes):
[image: iOS UI]

However, on android it looks like this:
[image: Android UI]

So everything is positioned a bit lower than where they should, causing the sound control to collide with the progress bar.

`build` method to reproduce:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (_videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized &&
            _chewieController.aspectRatio != null)
        ? ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _chewieController.aspectRatio!,
                child: Chewie(controller: _chewieController)))
        : AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: POST_IMAGE_ASPECT_RATIO,
            child: Center(
              child: DefaultCircularProgressIndicator(),
            ));
  }
```

I encounter this in the page where I view the posts items in my application (they have images, texts, videos, comments and more of that kind of generic items). I thought some other widget might have been causing the issue so I tried using various widgets to wrap the video player. Using `SafeArea` actually seemed to solve the misalignment issue but then I get another interesting problem which, on iOS looks like:
[image: iOS UI with SafeArea]

And on Android it looks like:
[image: Android UI with SafeArea]

So `SafeArea` causes some unwanted parts to appear.

`build` method to reproduce:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (_videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized &&
            _chewieController.aspectRatio != null)
        ? SafeArea(
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _chewieController.aspectRatio!,
                    child: Chewie(controller: _chewieController))))
        : AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: POST_IMAGE_ASPECT_RATIO,
            child: Center(
              child: DefaultCircularProgressIndicator(),
            ));
  }
```

I draw the red borders where I call this widget, I did not include that part of the code simply because I only added a container that only draws red borders and sets this video player as its child.

What could be causing this issue with `SafeArea`, and is there a way to fix the alignment issue on android without adding these whitespaces to the widget? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the Chewie widget in a theme widget with platform set to ios:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
  ),
  child: Chewie(
    controller: _chewieController,
  ),
)
```